# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis_cache-3.0.0-py3.6.egg'

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip

While docker image was being created, I've got the below exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis_cache-3.0.0-py3.6.egg'
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.6

# ...
```

**Packages:**

```
django==2.0.6
redis==3.5.3
django-redis-cache==2.0.0
django-redis-sessions
```

Here is a full trace of the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 75, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 121, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 265, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 152, in handle_pip_version_check
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 97, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 249, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 159, in user_agent
    setuptools_version = get_installed_version("setuptools")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 665, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 623, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1983, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1414, in has_metadata
    return self._has(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1854, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1731, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1688, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_redis_cache-3.0.0-py3.6.egg'
```

**Question:**

How can I overcome this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The only thing I can really think of is that Python thinks you are using Django 3.0, when you're actually using Django 2.0.6. You could maybe overcome this by changing sys.path

Comment: Thanks for your response, It's in the Dockerfile and runs by GitLab runner. I checked what you suggested and unfortunately, it was using Django 2.0.6. The problem might be from other dependencies.

Comment: Ok, to be honest, I'm an idiot xD. The FileNotFoundError said that django_redis_cache-3.0.0-py3.6 doesnt exist, and I just assumed that it was django that was wrong. It may be that the error I discussed above is applying to django-redis-cache. Im not sure though, so check if u want

Comment: please post the exact code you ran to generate this error

Comment: The command was `pip install -r requierments.txt`. I found it that was from another library that installed `django-redis-cache3`. It was quite interesting I've not supposed that.